# The ordinals as a free monoid-like entity

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, ordinals

Let $\kappa$ denote a fixed but arbitrary inaccessible cardinal. Call a set $\kappa$-small iff its cardinality is strictly less than $\kappa$. By a $\kappa$-suplattice, I mean a partially ordered set whose every $\kappa$-small subset has a join. Now recall that $\mathbb{N}$ can be characterized as the (additively-denoted) monoid freely generated by the set $\{1\}$. It seems likely that the ordinal numbers can be characterized similarly. To this end, define that a $\kappa$-*monarchy* is a $\kappa$-suplattice $S$ equipped with an (additively-denoted) monoid structure subject to two axioms:

**Axiom 0.** Addition is inflationary.

$$x+y \geq x, \qquad x+y \geq y$$

Note that these can be written as equations, e.g. $(x+y) \vee y = x+y$.

Hence $x+0 \geq 0$. So $0$ is the least element of $S$. Therefore $0$ is the join identity. In other words, the identity of the monoid structure is also the identity of the $\kappa$-suplattice structure.

**Axiom 1.** Addition on the left commutes with joins. Explicitly:

For all $\kappa$-small sets $I$ and all $I$-indexed sequences $x$ in $S,$ and all elements $y \in S$, we have:

$$y+\left(\bigvee_{i:I} x_i \right) = \left(\bigvee_{i:I} y+x_i \right)$$

> **Question.** It seems likely that the ordinals below $\kappa$ with their usual Cantorian operations form the free $\kappa$-monarchy on the set $\{1\}$. Is this correct?

*Discussion.*

Let $F_\kappa(\{1\})$ denote the $\kappa$-monarchy freely generated by $\{1\}$. Then $F_\kappa(\{1\})$ has an element that can play the role of $\omega$:

$$\omega := 1 \vee (1+1) \vee (1+1+1) \vee \cdots$$

It can be seen that $1+\omega=\omega$, using Axiom 1 followed by Axiom 0. I'm cautiously optimistic that the rest of the arithmetic will behave correctly, too. Ideas, anyone?

Comment: I would replace Axiom 0 by $y \geq 0$, i.e. that $0$ is the smallest element. Notice that $x+(-)$ is monotonic by Axiom 1, so $y \geq 0$ implies $x+y \geq x+0=x$. I am not sure if we really want $x+y \geq y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a $\kappa$-monarchy and $p \in P$. We want to show that there is a unique morphism $f : \kappa \to P$ of $\kappa$-monarchies such that $f(1)=p$. We define $f$ via transfinite recursion as follows. We let $f(0)=0$, $f(x+1)=f(x)+p$, and for limit ordinals $x$ we let $f(x) = \sup_{y<x} f(y)$. It is clear that we have to define $f$ this way, which proves uniqueness, and we only have to check that this $f$ is a morphism of $\kappa$-monarchies. It satisfies $f(0)=0$ and is continuous by construction. In order to prove $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, we use induction on $y$. The case $y=0$ is clear. If $y=z+1$ is a successor ordinal, then $$f(x+y)=f((x+z)+1)=f(x+z)+p = (f(x)+f(z))+p$$
$$= f(x)+(f(z)+p)=f(x)+f(z+1)=f(x)+f(y).$$
If $y$ is a limit ordinal, then (since $f$ is continuous)
$f(x+y) = \sup_{z<y} f(x+z)$ and hence $$f(x+y)=\sup_{z<y} (f(x)+f(z))=f(x)+\sup_{z<y} f(z)=f(x)+f(y).$$

Comment: Nice. Any idea how we might prove $\alpha+1>\alpha$ without assuming any prior facts about the ordinals? I've been trying (unsuccesfully) to prove this for a couple of days.

Comment: It's not true. Consider $\{0\}$.

Comment: In the $\kappa$-monarchy freely generated $1$, I mean.

Comment: There are lots of other properties familar from ordinal numbers which are not immediate corollaries from the two axioms. So probably one has to prove some of these first, in the correct order of course. And in the end, one may prove that $\alpha+(-)$ is strictly increasing.